# Saving order in ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I was able to save SQL in beauty way based on question [Save SQL to YAML as is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357103/save-sql-to-yaml-as-is/30358818).

Now, I should resolve issue with saving order in YAML as was before loading. So, I had YAML config as:

```
app:
  ....
conf:
  sql:
    ....
  mapping:
    ....
filters:
  ....
```

Once I save with **ruamel.yaml** I got random order saving as example below:

```
filters:
  ....
conf:
  mapping:
    ....
  sql:
    ....
app:
  ....
```

How can I save the keys of YAML-file as was loaded?

**Solution:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/30763929/4437954

Comment: YAML mappings and Python dictionaries are *unordered*. Use lists if order is important. See the [YAML mapping specification](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id932806): *A mapping node is an **unordered** collection of key: value pairs*.

Comment: Ah, it appears you can work around this by forcing the YAML parser to use OrderedDict objects; an `OrderedDict` lists contents in the order that you added keys. See the dupe.

Comment: You can tell YAML to load mappings as OrderedDicts. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21912744/866026) for how to do that.